# Возникла ошибка sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database

Tags: python, sql, pyrogram

Я не работаю с базами данных это ошибка произошла внутри pyrogram вот код ошибки:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-998' coro= 
<Client.handle_updates() done, defined at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/client.py:535>  exception=ProgrammingError('Cannot operate on a closed database.')>            
Traceback (most recent call last):                  
File  /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/client.py", line 567, in handle_updates                                     
diff = await self.invoke(
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                       
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/advanced/invoke.py", line 86, in invoke                             
await 
self.fetch_peers(getattr(r, "users", []))                                                   
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/client.py", line 531, in fetch_peers                                        
await self.storage.update_peers(parsed_peers)   
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyrogram/storage/sqlite_storage.py", line 129, in update_peers                       
self.conn.executemany() 
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed database.
```

Код где происходит эта ошибка:

```py
async def main():
     apps = os_name.sess_phone("y")
     print(apps)
     coros_start = [apps_start(i) for i in apps]
                    #print(coros_start)
     # Здесь происходит запуск клиентов app.start()            
     await asyncio.gather(*coros_start)
     section_url = await checks_section(button_url)
     coros = [running(l,section_url,0) for l in apps]
     print(coros)
     # Здесь выполняется определённая задача
     await asyncio.gather(*coros)
               
     coros_stop = [apps_stop(i) for i in apps]
                print("Both tasks have completed now.")
     # Здесь происходит закрытие клиента app.stop(), здесь и возникает ошибка        
     await asyncio.gather(*coros_stop)
                
                
task = asyncio.create_task(main())
await task
            
# Создание функции фабрики            
creater_observer(sources_name())
print("Бот Успешно Запущен!") 
app.run()
```